# Remove entry of a Bindinglist from a Linq results. - 2 birds in one shot?

Tags: c#, linq

This Query returns left outer join from two tables.

```
  var q = from adu in dtAdsUsers.AsEnumerable()
                        join elu in dtElUsers.AsEnumerable() on adu.Field<string>("samAccountName") equals elu.Field<string>("UserLogin") into gj
                        from au in gj.DefaultIfEmpty() //where au.Field<string>("UserLogin")==string.Empty
                        select
                        new
                        {
                            samAccount = adu.Field<string>("samAccountName"),
                            samb = (au == null ? string.Empty : au.Field<string>("UserLogin"))

                        };
```

Now remove entries from the dtAdusers which is bound to bindinglist bUserList,   using code like this

```
    foreach (var o in q)
                {

                if (o.samb != "")
                    {
                    Debug.WriteLine(o.samAccount);
                    IEnumerable<ADSUtilities.User> ud = from u in bUserList.AsEnumerable()
                                                        where u.sAMAccountName == o.samAccount
                                                        select u;

                    bUserList.RemoveAt(bUserList.IndexOf(ud));


                    }

                }
```

bUserList.RemoveAt(bUserList.IndexOf(ud))  gives invalid cast exception
1). How to resolve this ?
2). is there a Linq way of removing entries without iterating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ud` is an `IEnumerable` while the elements in `bUserList` are presumably not of `IEnumerable` this is why `bUserList.IndexOf(ud)` will fail.

If the query for `ud` can indeed result in multiple objects then you need to remove them 1 by 1 like this

```
foreach(var doomed in ud)
    bUserList.Remove(doomed);
```

If the query for `ud` is supposed to return only one element then you should change it to:

```
 ADSUtilities.User ud = bUserList.AsEnumerable().First(u => u.sAMAccountName == o.samAccount);
```

Then you can do: `bUserList.Remove(ud);`

Use `FirstOrDefault` if the query can result in no objects. This will return `default(T)` (which is `null` for reference types) instead of throwing an exception.

There is no real "Linq way" of removing elements from a list because you can't enumerate a list and remove items from it at the same time. This would result in an exception. So you always need to identify the items you want to delete first, store them in a separate list and then remove them. You could make an extension method for if you require it more often. Something like this:

```
 public static RemoveIf<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> cond)
 {
     var doomed = list.Where(cond).ToList();
     doomed.ForEach(x => list.Remove(x));
 }
```